# Java/Sql GUI PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, user-interface

I cant see why i am getting errors, I believe i did everything correct. I only seem to to get errors when i try to get the text out the combobx. Can someone please hep me do this well. I know how to insert data from a text field to a data with microsoft access . But not when it comes to combo boxes.

Theses errors

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at delete_me1.connection(delete_me1.java:66)
    at delete_me1$2.actionPerformed(delete_me1.java:133)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at delete_me1.connection(delete_me1.java:90)
    at delete_me1$2.actionPerformed(delete_me1.java:133)

Thanks :)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class delete_me1 {

    private JFrame frame;
    public JComboBox<?> comboBox;

    String MSAccessDriver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc ".trim();
    String MyDatabase = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\db\\Database.mdb";

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    delete_me1 window = new delete_me1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    public void connection() throws Exception {


        /*  String sql = "INSERT INTO animal (first_name, last_name) VALUES(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,animal);
        preparedStatemnt.setString(2,animalType);
        preparedStatemnt.executeUpdate();*/

        try {

            String com2 = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String com = textField.getText();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO client (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,com);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,com2);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


            Class.forName(MSAccessDriver);
            String db = "jdbc:odbc:Food"; // db = database string stored
                                            // in the database
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();
            st.execute(sql);

        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Save Complete Successfully");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public delete_me1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Dog", "Cat",
                "Cow", "Sheep" }));
        comboBox.setBounds(57, 54, 245, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    connection();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(57, 143, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(172, 144, 118, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc ".trim();` Why? Also, what error?

Comment: You have to initialize 'con' before you can use it

Comment: I did "   Connection con = null;"

Answer (score 0):

In other words, your question is "What is a null pointer exception?" It's what happens when a precondition for a subroutine in your program assumes a variable is not null when it uses that variable.

Now reading your error, "delete_me1.connection" is where there is a null value where there shouldn't be.